# Python Flask tutorial- running program, but visual studio isn't recognizing website/ import error

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code

I'm following tech with Tim's python website tutorial with Flask/visual studio. I'm only 14 min in and I'm facing an issue. I've typed everything in as he did and ran the program to no response. Initially it said 'ModuleNotFound: No module named website'. I then pip installed website.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjcYS.jpg

After I tried running it after pip installing website, I get the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\Dante\Desktop\flask Web App Tutorial> & C:/Users/Dante/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0/python.exe "c:/Users/Dante/Desktop/flask Web App Tutorial/website/main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Dante\Desktop\flask Web App Tutorial\website\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from website import create_app
ImportError: cannot import name 'create_app' from 'website' (C:\Users\Dante\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\website\__init__.py)
PS C:\Users\Dante\Desktop\flask Web App Tutorial>
```

Comment: Please give the link to tutorial and paste the code rather then images , you can format it using code formatted or ctrl+k

Comment: I ran this and it ran correctly on my machine and you don't need to install module website. delete it. there might be some problem with ide , try running it without ide using windows cmd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problems Explain:**

Because you run the app with `Run python file in terminal`, it tries to find the website package. In fact, it's just the website folder in your project, but you haven't added it to the launch.json file like this:

```
  "env": {
    "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"
  },
```

So, it cant find the website package. Then you try to install the website package through pip. But the website package you installed obviously has not `create_app` function which is created by youself. So you met the two problems you mentioned in your question.

**Right Way:**

You cant run the Flask app with the command: `Run python file in terminal`

You should run it like `python -m flask run`.

Usually, You can add a `Python Flask` debug configuration in the launch.json file. And then select it as the default debug configuration and run the app with `F5`.

**Suggestion:**

You can have a look at this [official doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask) related to the Flask tutorial, and download the example of it [here](https://github.com/microsoft/python-sample-vscode-flask-tutorial).